# KDE Plasma's Picture of the Day to Set Wallpaper not working

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-background

I try to set Bing's Picture of the Day as default Wallpaper.

[image]

It did not work as expected.

The other provides

[image]
[image]

My machine info:

```
$ neofetch --stdout
------------
OS: Ubuntu 19.04 x86_64
Host: MacBookPro11,1 1.0
Kernel: 5.0.0-31-generic
Uptime: 1 hour, 53 mins
Packages: 2374 (dpkg), 4 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.0.3
Resolution: 2560x1600
DE: KDE
WM: KWin
Theme: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK3]
Icons: breeze [KDE], breeze [GTK3]
CPU: Intel i5-4258U (4) @ 2.900GHz
GPU: Intel Haswell-ULT
Memory: 2703MiB / 3850MiB
```

Comment: No, other provider's wallpaper also does now work.

Comment: @DKBose ty I posted the screenshot of other provider.

Comment: No,does not see their picture. (the white line is the problem of command line screenshot tool of scrot https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot

Comment: I'll get back to you later but something is wrong. The Bing picture appears nearly at once. Some of the others may take a few seconds. `Scrot` should not be producing those lines!

Comment: it works now on 19.10